# how to onBackPressed() from another activity

Tags: android, onbackpressed

can we call another activity's the function onBackPresses() ?
for example, something like this:
---in second_activity----

```
if(i==10)
   first_activity.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: In what context you would need this?

Comment: main->second->third--(onBack)->main

Comment: I don't think you can, but I'm pretty sure you can achieve a similar behavior in other ways. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: You need to use `onBackPressed` in third activity if you want to return to mainactivity from there.

Comment: there is only a search in the second activity. after searching it is going to third activity(definition). i want this: if i press back, program should goes main activity

Comment: with onBackPressed, program doesn't return to main. program returns the previous activity so returns second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the first activity from the press of the back button on the third one, put this in your third activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```